# Laravel - refer variable passed in view to @include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have some includes that I need to add to my product page. Depending on the product I might need just a few of the includes and not all of them. So I want to do something like this:

```
@include('includes.info.'{{ $availableCategory->info_path }})
```

Is something like this possible and if not what is the best way to go around it?

Comment: have you tried send some data from controller and then @include($myInclude) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
@include('includes.info.' . $availableCategory->info_path )

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@include($someView)
```

Just tested and it works.

Comment: Won't I just pass data from my view to the include that way? I just need to know which file I should include. I don't need to pass any data to the includes.'

Comment: I tried it and it works. It is a nice solution, although I like the one provided by @RahmanQaiser a little bit more.